# How to show markers with coloured circles?

Tags: android, google-maps, geometry, icons, marker

i have created this activity:

```
public class MapViewer extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private Database db = new Database(this);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapviewer);

        try {
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (map != null) {
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);

                this.addMerchantMarkers(new MarkerOptions());
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (map != null) {
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
            map.setTrafficEnabled(false);
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void addMerchantMarkers(MarkerOptions mo) {
        SQLiteDatabase dbRead = db.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor result = dbRead.rawQuery("SELECT title, addr, lat, lon FROM users", null);

        while(result.moveToNext()) {            
            map.addMarker(mo.position(new LatLng(result.getFloat(2), result.getFloat(3)))
                    .title(result.getString(0))
                    .snippet(result.getString(1))
                    );;
        }
    }
}
```

Since there are more than 5000 markers i get something like this:

[image]

I would like to get something like this:

[image]

that shows circles for markers that are closer to eachother and if you zoom it shows smaller circles or unique markers.
How to obtain this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marker clustering lib by google 
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering

Comment: This works, thank you. Now how to add title, snippet and custom icon to every ClusterItem?

Comment: use library, it also provide custom marker, use demo sample of library

Comment: I see but it is totally different. Please can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747435/how-to-set-details-for-infowindow-using-clusteritem ?